# Make a auto clicker that clicks while I'm holding left click

Tags: python, python-3.x, pynput

As I said, I'm pretty new to coding and python, and I need to make an auto clicker that toggles when I hold left click and stops when i release the button. The current code makes a key bind that toggles it off and on. I was searching the web for the last few days and couldn't find anything. Thanks in advance!

```
import time
import threading
import random
from pynput.mouse import Button, Controller
from pynput.keyboard import Listener, KeyCode


x = (0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 0.11)
delay = random.choice(x)
button = Button.left
start_stop_key = KeyCode(char='s')
exit_key = KeyCode(char='e')


class ClickMouse(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, delay, button):
        super(ClickMouse, self).__init__()
        self.delay = delay
        self.button = button
        self.running = False
        self.program_running = True

    def start_clicking(self):
        self.running = True

    def stop_clicking(self):
        self.running = False

    def exit(self):
        self.stop_clicking()
        self.program_running = False

    def run(self):
        while self.program_running:
            while self.running:
                mouse.click(self.button)
                time.sleep(self.delay)
            time.sleep(0.1)


mouse = Controller()
click_thread = ClickMouse(delay, button)
click_thread.start()


def on_press(key):
    if key == start_stop_key:
        if click_thread.running:
            click_thread.stop_clicking()
        else:
            click_thread.start_clicking()
    elif key == exit_key:
        click_thread.exit()
        listener.stop()


with Listener(on_press=on_press) as listener:
    listener.join()
mouse = Controller()
click_thread = ClickMouse(delay, button)
click_thread.start()


def on_press(key):
    if key == start_stop_key:
        if click_thread.running:
            click_thread.stop_clicking()
        else:
            click_thread.start_clicking()
    elif key == exit_key:
        click_thread.exit()
        listener.stop()


with Listener(on_press=on_press) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

Comment: After looking over your code I see that the approach that I would use is very different from the ones you have chosen. Consider what pyautogui can do for you. Is the separate thread to drive it necessary? I suspect it may be an unnecessary complication. The keyboard input from a command council terminal is also potentially troublesome. So I keep going back and forth in my head as to whether I can give you a helpful answer or not. Please tell me more on how you want to use your clicker and if you are open to other approaches?

Answer (score 0):

For what it is worth, I would look to this approach:
[PyAutoGUI Chapter](https://automatetheboringstuff.com/2e/chapter20/)

With full documentation here:
[PyAutoGUI Docs:](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)